How to use DESC in a LISTAGG function in Snowflake to organize concatenated data in decreasing order?
I am using following query in Snowflake to get the SKU # and their processing dates using LISTAGG function
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, LISTAGG(DISTINCT Date, ';')
FROM SKU_Data


I want to use the DESC for the LISTAGG function so I can have dates in descending order. I modify the upper query into following
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, LISTAGG(DISTINCT Date, ';' DESC)
FROM SKU_Data

But I having an error.

Please read: why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.

I having an error. is absolutely meaningless if you don't provide the exact error message.

reading the documents helps: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg can help. Above the fold it mentions ordering and sorting, and how the syntax is, and the examples show valid SQL.

You need to use WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY date DESC).
SELECT
  sku,
  LISTAGG(DISTINCT date, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY date DESC) AS date_list
FROM sku_data
GROUP BY sku

